# What would cause 1/2 of a circuit to start flickering but not trip the breaker?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, circuit-breaker

I have a 1950s brick ranch with the original ungrounded BX wiring. The other day the lights started flickering from on to completely off for seconds at a time. I started taking stock in what rooms the circuit was tied to and it’s tied to my bedroom, bathroom, living room, hallway, and 1/2 of my basement outlets. I have perfect functionality from my basement outlets but everything else isn’t working at all how it should. I turned off the breaker that was causing issues but I’m stumped on what’s going on. If I had to guess there’s a loose connection somewhere in between but how would I go about trying to find it?

Comment: I will assume that stuff is not messed up with electronics.  Old style lights and plain simple breakers.  Loose connection somewhere is probably a good guess.  You find the loose connection/s the hard way, turn off the breaker and check each connection/wire nut for tightness.

Comment: Sounds about right. The old owner did some crazy shit when he wired stuff so it’s going to be a total mess

Comment: Newer/more recent code than 1950s require all connections to be torque, so getting a torque screwdriver is not a bad idea.  Take pictures if something looks funny and before you remove wires.  Funny stuff we might be able to help with, connecting wires back right without pictures is much harder.

Comment: We just had this happen - half the house worked fine, half didn't. Turned out to be a connection issue at the utility's electrical pole with one of the two phases; phase A had the usual 120 volts, phase B was coming into the box with *one* volt.

Comment: I thought that but it’s not half the house. It’s tied to a single circuit and only part of that single circuit unfortunately

Comment: To be clear, is it just the light bulb flickering... Or are the other outlets in the house having issues?

Answer (score 3):

The breaker is only protecting your cables from overcurrent, not everything else that is dangerous (leakage current and arc faults).

Leakage currents are interrupted by an RCD, and arc faults are interrupted by an AFDD.

In your case you have a bad connection somewhere, resulting in an arcing connection. Arcing connections get hot and can result in an fire. Even in an brick house there are enough combustible materials around therefor that issue should get resolved ASAP.

I gather that you have already identified the faulty branch. The part of the "perfectly working outlets" could be treacherous, as certain appliances attached to an outlet could still work fine, even with an arcing connection.

I'd get a night lamp, with an good old incandescent bulb, and check the outlets for flickering. With an idea of the rough structure of the cabling you could then find a coarse location of the bad connection.

Comment: Good point, I’ll try that. I have a fluke DMM that I’ll bring home and use to check the voltages at the outlets themselves. See if there’s any major fluctuations for the ones that seem fine.

Comment: even the good DMM aren't fast enough to detect flickering

Comment: This isn’t just a little flicker. It’s turning on and off for seconds at a time

Answer (score 2):

> how would I go about trying to find it?

- identify the breaker
- turn off only that one breaker
- identify all wall outlets that do not have power from turning off that one breaker
- check each of those wall outlets for wire breakage and bad connection - inspect/reconnect the wires and/or replace the outlet

had a rental that got trashed, tenants broke doors... kicked wall outlets.  You bump a particular wall outlet in the bedroom and everything downstream of it would either flicker or go out completely (bathroom lights, lights in other rooms, etc).  Other outlet near it obviously was beat on and looked like it would've been the problem but was not, it was another outlet that looked ok.

you don't need to use a DMM, other than to verify no voltage before working on an outlet.  Otherwise you will likely use the DMM incorrectly and see "voltage" everywhere and then go hmmm nothing seems to be wrong.

if the outlet is wired using its push in connector (quickwire) then if it can be undone connect it via the screw terminals if possible to rule out a faulty quickconnect part of the outlet.  The problem will be at an outlet that has 2 or more hot (black) wires, if the outlet has only one hot wire to it it's not that one.

Comment: Do you have any tips on how to trace wires when they’re inside the walls?

Comment: The "breaker finder" things can be (ab) used to trace live wires, if you turn up their amplifier sufficiently. There are better tools which power the transmitter from a battery and don't care if the circuit is live or not, but they cost an order of magnitude mire unless you get lucky on eBay. Maybe two orders of magnitude.

Comment: So I was looking at a circuit tracer but my issue is that it requires a circuit ground. Mine is old 2 wire electrical. Can I unplug the hot from the breaker and put the toner to that and then the panel box ground?

Comment: start with the wall outlets, bx or romex within walls doesn't just go bad you do not need to trace wires within the walls.  you even said previous owner did some crazy shit, so that being evident unless he did some wall work the problem will be externally accessible.

Comment: +1. Not just the walls though; ceilings too. As well as where lights are hanging or inside of the boxes inside of the can lights. - There's no tracing wires. There's, you open up *everything*. - I'd VTC this question as a dupe, except there's never been a good answer (because there isn't one) to *how to not have to do that*. @Burg

Answer (score 0):

A loose or bad connection.

Open the breaker.
Verify the circuit is OFF.
Check all connections in the circuit that is flashing.